# parsing the content of a text file line by line using java

Tags: java, string, parsing, field, line

```
3375577.3   131  STSTWMS
3375577.4   131  STSTWMS
3407108     131  STSTWMS
3407231     131  STSTWMS
3407280.1   131  STSTWMS
3407581     131  STSTWMS
3408483     131  STSTWMS
3409015     131  STSTWMS
3409015.1   131  STSTWMS
3409085.1   131  STSTWMS
3409364     131  STSTWMS
3409364.1   131  STSTWMS
```

my text file have the above format.

each line represents the information related to a patch
with the first colum is patch id, the second column is the release and the third one represent a client.
how can i read the file line by line storing patchs into an array list and parsing the fields into columns

Comment: Post what you have tried?

Answer (score 0):

Just look up: BufferedReader from FileReader -> readLine()

And Split Them with String.split

And add to ArrayList with add()

... Really sometimes Java ist just like writing what you want to do in plain english

Answer (score 0):

Your requirement is achievable using readLine() method in java BufferedReader. Eash line can be stored in an ArrayList and then each String can be split to get the individual words.

To split string you can try using **StringTokenizer** class. Sample usage is as follows:

```
StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(str);
while (st.hasMoreElements()) {
    System.out.println(st.nextElement());
}
```

This code will remove all spaces from the string.

Comment: FileInputStream fstream = new FileInputStream("c:\\Downloads\\ibm10_20140416.list");
     DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(fstream);
         BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
     String strLine;
     while ((strLine = br.readLine()) != null)   {
       System.out.println (strLine);
       String[] columns = strLine.split("  ");  
    String patch_id = columns[0];  
          String release = columns[1];  
          String client = columns[2];

Comment: 3375577.3   131  STSTWMS
3407108     131  STSTWMS

Comment: 3375577.3   131  STSTWMS
3407108     131  STSTWMS                                                  the parsing of the first line is doing well but in  the second i can display the 3 field(STSTWMS). i think because of the  split the first line have 2 spaces while the second one have 3 spaces

Comment: I have updated my answer. You can try using StringTokenizer instead of String.split method

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Scanner](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) class' `nextLine()` method to read the text line by line. As to how to store it as columns, in each line, find the character(s) by which the each column is split, eg: a space `' '` or any other, and use this in the [String](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html) class' `split()` method.

Try something like this:

```
File file = new File("input.txt");
Scanner s = new Scanner(file);
while (s.hasNextLine()){
String string = s.nextLine();
List<String> columns = Arrays.asList(string.split(" "));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

version with BufferedReader as wrote above

```
String line="";

 BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));

while((line = r.readline) != null){

  List<String> columns = Arrays.asList(line.split(" "));

}
```

Comment: problem solved by adding this line:                                        String[] columns = strLine.split("\\s{2,4}");